# Cannot Print 13 X 19 paper on Epson WF7710 from Photoshop or MS Photo Viewer

Tags: printing, printer

I cannot create a custom paper size on my Epson WF 7710 Printer. It will print 13 X 19 but it's not an option on my computer or my husband's computer. But it DOES come up as an option on my friend's computer and she prints 13 X 19 all the time.

User created or custom paper size not an option
Biggest paper size listed is 11 X 17
My OS is Windows 10
Tried printing from MS Photo Viewer and Photoshop
Print Settings and Properties provide no option for custom size 
I know 13 X 19 size is called Super B - not an option from either computer.

Thanks for any help!!